# Accent on second syllable for "preference"

Tags: pronunciation

Dictionaries say that the word "preference" has got the accent on the first syllable.

In a film the actor Jonny Lee Miller pronounced it with accent on the second syllable. 
It was not the first time I heard somebody pronounce it that way.

Where does it come from?

Comment: Perhaps there is some influence here from the word _preferment_ which is normally accented on the second syllable?

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted pronunciation, at least in Britain, is PREFerence. That is what is preFERRED, and the one that I particularly preFER.  (Note how the emphasis changes).

But "preFERence" does seem a possibility - if one were needing to add stress to the word.